# How to Add the exe to the AppX package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iot, windows-10-desktop

In trying to get [this code](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS) sample working on Windows 10 (prior to running on Windows IoT) with Visual Studio 2017, I've run up against this message:

```
Add the exe to the AppX package
```

Also, when reading [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/iot/samples/externalprocesslauncher) it states:

> When a relative path is specified; such as SampleConsoleApp.exe,
>   .\SampleConsoleApp.exe or a subfolder, subfolder\SampleConsoleApp.exe,
>   the ProcessLauncher API looks for the exe file starting at the package
>   root of the AppX deployed.

I thought the exe in question could then be part of the project being run and would be allowed permission to execute. However, I get this error:

```
Exception Thrown: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

How do I "add the exe to the AppX package"?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. If you want to launch another EXE from UWP on the desktop you can reference [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a78aa7b8-9d80-4282-8ecb-1496b2535c81/uwpaccess-denied-another-exe-module-by-desktop-bridge?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: I know you didn’t say this directly, but are you implying that the instructions in the article I referenced are not valid for the Windows 10 desktop but only only for Windows IoT?

Comment: The ProcessLauncher API belongs to Windows IoT Extension SDK. So, you are right. [These Extension SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/) introduce some other APIs does not belong to Universal Windows Platform by default in order to target specific devices.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am wondering why it is not possible to test (potentially a lot of) software on a Windows machine without a device (outside of requirement specific hardware.)

Comment: There is no emulator for Windows IoT Core. You can try to set up a Virtual Machine. You can check these related threads:[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8dc8022c-451f-4b45-9c6d-af3c7d43169e/how-to-deploy-windows-10-iot-rasp-pi-image-as-a-virtual-machine?forum=WindowsIoT) and [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c0cf17d3-d88c-43dc-a34b-8a197cd6c1ab/windows-iot-core-in-an-emulator?forum=WindowsIoT).